# How divide HTML Page vertically into 4 sections

Tags: html, css

I want divide my HTML Page into 4 different vertical sections .

I want each section to have a different background color, for that I used div but  it each background color does not cover the sides of each section.

** My  aspire end result:
I don't want to see the  color red of the body background color in the html.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.intro {
  background-color: #674AB3;
}

.edu {
  background-color: #A348A6;
}

.Skills {
  background-color: #9F63C4;
}

.end {
  background-color: #9075D8;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">

  <hr>
</div>
<div class="edu">

  <hr>
</div>
<div class="Skills">

  <hr>
</div>
<div class="end">

  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: can you be more clear about your question please. Like what do you mean by dividing?

Comment: I want my page to consist of 4  different sections

Answer (score 2):

1. Set `margin: 0` for body, it has a defualt margin.
2. Set `<hr>`'s margin to 0.
3. Set height for each div to be `25vh` (vertical height).

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.intro {
  background-color: #674AB3;
  height: 25vh;
}

.edu {
  background-color: #A348A6;
  height: 25vh;
}

.Skills {
  background-color: #9F63C4;
  height: 25vh;
}

.end {
  background-color: #9075D8;
  height: 25vh;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <hr/>
</div>
<div class="edu">
  <hr/>
</div>
<div class="Skills">
  <hr/>
</div>
<div class="end">
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: it's works but I want also want it work in the bottom of each section as well .

Comment: @RonGoldstein added the hr with margin 0

Answer (score 2):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-container>div {

margin:30px;
}
.flex-container hr {
   
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-width: 5px;
}

.intro {
  background-color: #674AB3;
}

.edu {
  background-color: #A348A6;
}

.Skills {
  background-color: #9F63C4;
}

.end {
  background-color: #9075D8;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="intro"><hr></div>
  <div class="edu"><hr></div>
  <div class="Skills"><hr></div>
  <div class="end"><hr></div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to remove hr tag then please add this css: 

.flex-container>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
margin:30px;
}

It's working awesome :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using **grid**! might as well make it responsive :D

This is to have 4 sections laying one next to another, to make them stack in the vertical direction, change:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
```

to:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #00000000; /* transparent color */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* 4 vertical sections */
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.intro {
  background-color: #674AB3;
}

.edu {
  background-color: #A348A6;
}

.Skills {
  background-color: #9F63C4;
}

.end {
  background-color: #9075D8;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
    <p>intro</p>
</div>
<div class="edu">
    <p>edu</p>
</div>
<div class="Skills">
    <p>Skills</p>
</div>
<div class="end">
    <p>end</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.intro {
  height:200px;
  background-color: #674AB3 !important;
}

.edu {
  height:200px;
  background-color: #A348A6 !important;;
}

.Skills {
  height:200px;
  background-color: #9F63C4 !important;;
}

.end {
  height:200px;
  background-color: #9075D8 !important;;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">

  <hr>
</div>
<div class="edu">

  <hr>
</div>
<div class="Skills">

  <hr>
</div>
<div class="end">

  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach as well.

```css
body {background-color:transparent;}

.intro {
  background-color: #674AB3;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}

.edu {
  background-color: #A348A6;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}

.Skills {
  background-color: #9F63C4;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}

.end {
  background-color: #9075D8;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="intro">
Hello
</div>

<div class="edu">
Hello
</div>
<div class="Skills">
Hello
</div>
<div class="end">
Hello
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simmply use display: flex to the parent container which is flex-container

like

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="intro"><hr></div>
  <div class="edu"><hr></div>
  <div class="Skills"><hr></div>
  <div class="end"><hr></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="intro">
    
    </div>
    <div class="edu">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Skills">

    </div>
    <div class="end">

    </div>
</div>

body {
  background-color: red;
}
.main{
    display: flex;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    width:100vw;
}
.intro {
  background-color: #674AB3;
  width: 25%;
  height: 75vh;
}

.edu {
  background-color: #A348A6;
  width: 25%;
      height: 75vh;
}

.Skills {
  background-color: #9F63C4;
  width: 25%;
      height: 75vh;
}

.end {
  background-color: #9075D8;
  width: 25%;
      height: vh;
}
```

[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA06k.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main">

    <div class="intro">
    
    </div>
    <div class="edu">
    
    </div>
    <div class="Skills">

    </div>
    <div class="end">

    </div>
```

```
.main{
    display: flex;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    width:100vw;
}
.intro {
  background-color: #674AB3;
  width: 25%;
  height: 75vh;
}

.edu {
  background-color: #A348A6;
  width: 25%;
  height: 75vh;
}

.Skills {
  background-color: #9F63C4;
  width: 25%;
  height: 75vh;
}

.end {
  background-color: #9075D8;
  width: 25%;
  height:75vh;
}
```